# how to decouple alignment of rows within a column in LyX?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lyx

How do I decouple the paragraph alignment of rows within a column in LyX? I would like my top row to be aligned in the centre, and all subsequent (content) rows to be aligned left.

However, whenever I try to align any of them, the alignment for the entire column will change. Is there a workaround this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to active a "multi-column" mode for the entry. This is done by inserting your cursor in the cell you want to set in a different alignment and clicking on the "set multi-column" button in the tabular toolbar (second from the right):

[image]

You can then select any of the alignment options to update it for that specific cell. The eventual code will resemble:

```
% Preview body

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
First column & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Second column} & Last column\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
A & B & C\tabularnewline
\hline 
A lengthy entry & Another lengthy entry & Yet another lengthy entry\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

The important thing to note in the code is the use of `\multicolumn{1}{<align>}{<stuff>}`, which resets the alignment to `<align>`, based on your selection.

---

You can also revert back to the LaTeX way of doing things. As such, use an ERT:

[image]

[image]

```
% Preview body

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
First column & Second column & Last column\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
A & B & C\tabularnewline
\hline 
A lengthy entry & Another lengthy entry & Yet another lengthy entry\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
First column & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Second column} & Last column\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
A & B & C\tabularnewline
\hline 
A lengthy entry & Another lengthy entry & Yet another lengthy entry\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```